# springboot using poi download excel dosen't work

Tags: excel, spring-boot, vue.js, apache-poi

here's the thing. I user springboot as backend and vue as frontend to export excel. The code of springboot is as:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download/cellInfo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void downLoadCellFile(@RequestParam String countyCode,
                                                            @RequestParam String cellCode,
                                                            HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
       configService.downLoad(countyCode, cellCode,response);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("error:", e);
    }
}

  public void downLoad(String countyCode, String cellCode, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    String fileName = createFileName(countyCode,cellCode);

    response.setHeader("content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8"));


    List<Residential> residentialList = residentialService.listResidents(countyCode,cellCode);

    Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("用户信息");
    Row head = sheet.createRow(0);
    head.createCell(0).setCellValue("楼栋");
    head.createCell(1).setCellValue("单元");
    head.createCell(2).setCellValue("门牌");
    head.createCell(3).setCellValue("用户号");
    head.createCell(4).setCellValue("用户姓名");
    head.createCell(5).setCellValue("联系电话");
    head.createCell(6).setCellValue("详细安装地址");
    head.createCell(7).setCellValue("表口径");
    head.createCell(8).setCellValue("设备地址");

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    if(residentialList!=null&&residentialList.size()>0) {
        for (Residential residential : residentialList) {
            Row body = sheet.createRow(sheet.getLastRowNum()+1);
            body.createCell(0).setCellValue(residential.getUnitCode().split("-")[0]);
            body.createCell(1).setCellValue(residential.getUnitCode().split("-")[1]);
            body.createCell(2).setCellValue(residential.getRoomCode());

        }
         fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        fos.close();
    }


    response.flushBuffer();
    ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    workbook.write(outputStream);
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();

    return ;
}
```

and the code of vue is as:

```
   handleExport() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.exportList.length; i++) {
    this.$axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: address + "/config/download/cellInfo",
      params: {countyCode:this.exportList[i].countyCode,
              cellCode:this.exportList[i].cellCode},
    responseType: 'blob'
    })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
          const blob = new Blob([res.data],{type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});
          let filename ='1.xls';
          //创建一个超链接，将文件流赋进去，然后实现这个超链接的单击事件
          const elink = document.createElement('a');
          elink.download = filename;
          elink.style.display = 'none';
          elink.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          document.body.appendChild(elink);
          elink.click();
          URL.revokeObjectURL(elink.href); // 释放URL 对象
          document.body.removeChild(elink);

        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('失败', err)
        })
  }
  this.exportDialogVisible = false;
}
```

Now the problem is the request returns 200 and but the download doesn't start, and the console of the vue is undefined.
It confused me several days. Any help will be grateful.

Comment: So is the error in Springboot or Vue or Excel. Isolate the line that errors and update your question.

Comment: I guess the problem is caused by the separation of front end and backend. I send the request to the backend directly and the file can be download normaly

Comment: So you expect us to work in this based on a **guess**???